# How do I let my cloudbees build jobs access external servers on ec2

Tags: cloudbees

I have a series of build jobs (using maven in this case) that want to access some of my own infrastructure (eg MySQL, Cassandra) for testing - how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running your own servers in EC2 US-East, you can open up to the build service security group as per the article - [Allowing Access to EC2 Resources](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/support-kb-articles/DEV-at-cloud/Allowing-Access-to-EC2-Resources-from-CloudBees-Slaves.html)

Comment: This page is no longer updated, I get an error sayinCould not update your security group rules (No changes were made): The security group 'hudson-master' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-xxxxxxxx'

Comment: This guide is only useful if your resources are located in US-EAST-1 in an EC2 classic network. VPC / other regions are not supported.